# Is there an rpm to install wxPython in linux

Tags: python, wxpython

Am trying to install wxPython on my Suse 10 Desktop, but am not successful.

Is there an rpm i can use to install or set of instructions that i can follow to install  wxPython (2.8.12).

Gath.

Comment: Seems legit: http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/3/srodzaj/1/search/wxPython

Answer (score 1):

Installation instructions:
http://wiki.wxpython.org/InstallingOnUbuntuOrDebian

RPMs: http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=wxPython